# Select a Div element with some value to Increase the Final Amount

Tags: javascript, html

Yesterday I found help to solve an issue, how to affect final price with inputs with specific values. In this case I want to lear to do it using divs directly. This is My actual Code

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("no_selection").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector(".priceText1").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1" id="total">$0.00</h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>

<div id="quotingArea2">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemProduct">
      <h4 class="itemText">
        <span class="no_selection">Logos</span>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="itemHidden">
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">First Option</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">Second Option</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">Third Option</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think I'm doing something wrong hehehe. someone can help me?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing , mention that

Comment: Hello @IronyStack trying to achieve that by clicking on one <span class="no_selection">Second Option</span> (somehow add a money value to each one) that affects the #priceText value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a price to add, so I added an input so you can type the price. You also need the checks to be able to include it or not in the budget. And you need a button to compute the final price.

It could be something like this:

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].classList.contains('selected')) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i< spans.length; i++){
    spans[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.setAttribute("class", "selected");
        totalIt();
    });
}
```

```css
.selected{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1" id="total">$0.00</h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>

<div id="quotingArea2">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemProduct">
      <h4 class="itemText">
        <span class="no_selection">Logos</span>
        <input class="money" value="300" type="hidden" />
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="itemHidden">
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">First Option</span>
          <input class="money" value="100" type="hidden" />
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">Second Option</span>
          <input class="money" value="50" type="hidden" />
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="itemHiddenUnselected">
        <h4 class="itemText">
          <span class="no_selection">Third Option</span>
          <input class="money" value="10" type="hidden" />
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias! pero es posible que se calcule sólo? la idea es que de manera oculta yo le ponga un valor a cada opción (first option, second option, etc) y si lo clickean (sin tener checkbox, si no directamente el texto) se sume automáticamente según el valor que yo le doy a cada uno? es decir, que yo clickqueé first option y en el priceText1 cambie a $6.00 ya que el valor de first option sea 6$?

Comment: Yes of course is possible. You can can hide the input field changing the type to hidden: `<input class="money" type="number" />` and you can remove the checkbox and change the click event to use the click on the <span>.

Comment: thanks pal! I've tried but didn't well. I want to get rid of the calculate button too, just trying to display the new amount only by clicking one itemText.

this is what I did with your answer but is not working:(

HTML

Comment: I've edited the example to achieve what you want. I hope I understand you correctly.